# I get an error when using redirectAction with struts2 and portlets inside jboss portal

Tags: redirect, struts2, jboss-portal

I have the following struts.xml:

`<struts>

    <package name="default" namespace="/view" extends="struts-portlet-default">

         <action name="index" class="com.gigi.LoginAction">

             <result type="redirectAction">

                 <param name="actionName">showAlerts</param>

                 <param name="namespace">/view</param>

                 <param name="portletMode">view</param>

             </result>

             <result name="error">/includes/error.jsp</result>

         </action>

         <action name="showAlerts" class="com.gigi.AlertsAction">

             <result>/jsp/view/Alerts.jsp</result>

         </action>

    </package>

    <package name="edit" namespace="/edit" extends="struts-portlet-default">

        <action name="index" class="com.gigi.UpdateNameAction">

            <result type="redirectAction">

                <param name="actionName">index</param>

                <param name="portletMode">view</param>

            </result>

            <result name="input">/jsp/edit/index.jsp</result>

        </action>

    </package>

</struts>`

and LoginAction has the following execute method:

```
 public String execute() throws Exception {

  boolean loggedIn = checkLogin();

  System.out.println("LoggedIn = " + loggedIn);
  if (loggedIn) {
   return SUCCESS;
  }

  return ERROR;
 }
```

I am trying a redirect from LoginAction to AlertsAction. Every time I open the portlet in jboss portal 2.7.1, I get the following error:

> *The requested resource (/portlet/view/showAlerts) is not available*

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? 
I tried writing the redirect in different ways, but the result is the same...
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Where exactly is Alerts.jsp?  Is it in /jsp or /WEB-INF/jsp?  Can you log something out of the execute() method of AlertsAction?

Comment: the jsp is in the /jsp folder of the webapp.
I talked to some collegues and it seems that in the portlet the redirectAction doesn't work very well, so I am using chain.